# Error in R code for creating a model using KNN algorithm for text mining

Tags: r, text-mining, knn

I am trying to do some text mining over 35000 rows of data, and when i try to create the model  from modeldata, I take the rows that I decided to use for training and test. And, I also feed the known categories of the training data into the model.

I am getting this error .

Error in knn(modeldata[train, ], modeldata[test, ], cl[train]) : 
  too many ties in knn

Any suggestions how to fix it.

I have set the seed for 100.

Regards,
Ren.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156229/error-too-many-ties-in-knn-in-r) will help.

Comment: I tried the same and still the error message

Comment: I don't know much about this function, you could raise an issue on the package github repo, if it has one.

Comment: Thanks will try it over there

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the source code defines the maximum number of ties to be 1000.
See [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/error-in-knn-too-many-ties-in-knn-td3798689.html) for an answer at the R mailing list or [here](https://github.com/cran/class/blob/master/src/class.c) for the source.

If you simulate your data maybe you should think about if your data simulation scheme is realistic. Alternative you cloud try different implementations like,
https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=kknn
https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=FNN 
...